# Philosophy books for mathematicians

Tags: reference-request, symbolic-logic, mathematical-logic

Are there any books on philosophy that make relatively heavy use of math? I'm not looking for anything on formal epistemology, logic, or philosophy of math. Two examples of books that fall in the category I'm interested in are [*Infinity Causation and Paradox*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198810334) by Alexaner Pruss and [*Philosophical Perspectives on Infinity*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521860679) by Graham Oppy. But I'd like to find something that isn't about paradoxes of infinity.

Comment: Would you be interested in the attempts to derive morality from purely logical premises?

Comment: sure, do you know of a book on that?

Comment: I haven't read one, but I _think_ Spinoza did some of that.

Comment: Two of my favorites from the turn of the last century are Frege, The Foundation of Arithmetic, and Whitehead, The Concept of Nature. One that I didn't care for but was highly regarded at the time is Carnap, The Logical Structure of the World. You can probably get them all online for free. Oops, just went back and read your question again. Frege is arguably philosophy of math.

Comment: [Hofstadter, Gödel, Escher, Bach](https://www.physixfan.com/wp-content/files/GEBen.pdf), [Gangle, Diagrammatic Immanence: Category Theory and Philosophy](https://ndpr.nd.edu/reviews/diagrammatic-immanence-category-theory-and-philosophy/), [Corfield, Towards a Philosophy of Real Mathematics](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/TOWARDS-A-PHILOSOPHY-OF-REAL-MATHEMATICS-Davies/a05f56e1d6f1243582e0ccb39d8772e2bf6cc557), [Rickles, Quantum Gravity: A Primer for Philosophers](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/5387/).

Comment: [Lakatos, Proofs and refutations](https://dl1.cuni.cz/pluginfile.php/730446/mod_resource/content/2/Imre%20Lakatos%3B%20Proofs%20and%20Refutations.pdf), [Steinhart, More Precisely: The Math You Need to Do Philosophy](https://www.pdfdrive.com/more-precisely-the-math-you-need-to-do-philosophy-e158262532.html).

Comment: May I put in a word for Fernando Zalamea. https://www.amazon.com/Peirces-Logic-Continuity-Conceptual-Mathematical/dp/0983700494 and especially https://www.amazon.com/Synthetic-Philosophy-Contemporary-Mathematics-Fernando/dp/0956775012 He seems to be one of the few philosophers to understand modern (post-1950) mathematics rather than being stuck in the Frege-Russell era.

Comment: Note that most philosophy is based on nebulous word salads and any request for precision is met with scorn or censorship. If a book is firmly based on mathematical or even purely logical reasoning, then it is either applied logic/mathematics or rarer than finding a diamond in a pile of cow pies.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you could try *Being and Event* by Badiou, it's regarded as a bit controversial by some, but influence of Badiou is constantly growing in modern philosophy(for instance in so called Speculative Realism).
He is basically building ontology based on Set Theory there. I believe that without decent background in Set Theory this book is nearly impossible to comprehend.

Comment: Badiou’s writing using mathematics and physics was criticized as being fundamentally flawed as addressed in “Fashionable Nonsense” by mathematician Alan Sokal. I, too, am a mathematician. Badiou’s use of mathematics illustrates a foundational lack of understanding of the subject.